# Tableau, Action on Non-Map messes up Double Map

Tags: filter, maps, action, tableau-api

[First workbook on Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings/BusinessRatings) allows user to hover or select datapoints on two separate maps, and other panels react accordingly (refer to tab `Business Ratings`)

Two maps are filtered separately, i.e. businesses in Brooklyn are selected in Brooklyn map, businesses in Ludhiana are selected in Ludhiana map, and it worked really well .... so far

[image]

[Second workbook on Public Tableau](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings-Grade/BusinessRatings) adds action to `Grade` panel. If user hovers over a business, only that business should display on one of the maps.

[image]

But the problem, it displays on BOTH maps, which is what I don't want. And when I check the Location(Location) filter, it selects ALL locations, instead of the ones I specified. It's as if adding action to `Grade` totally wiped out my efforts.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I solved my problem.

Before, `Grand_Avg` was defined as

```
{ EXCLUDE [Location (Location)] : AVG([Number_Rating]) }
```

So when I created action to select `[Location (Location)]`, it somehow removed the filters I originally placed on `[Location (Location)]` for both separate maps.

But now, I defined `Grand_Avg` as

```
{ EXCLUDE [Location] : AVG([Number_Rating]) }
```

And now, I can create action to Hover and Select the Location in `Grade` panel and it works better. [Here is updated workbook.](https://public.tableau.com/profile/sonihal#!/vizhome/LocalBusinessRatings-GradeSolved/BusinessRatings)